# Has string theory been able to produce masses of elementary particles?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, string-theory, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model

Masses of elementary particles in standard model are strange numbers. Is it possible to obtain these masses in string theory (presumably by using very few number of input parameters)?

Comment: Mass has dimension, it might be more meaningful to reproduce dimensionless constant, e.g. mass ratio between up and down quarks.

Answer (score 4):

If you know which string theory vacuum you have (which compactification, which fluxes etc) and you know how the symmetries are broken, then you could in principle compute the masses.

Alas, nobody knows which is the right vacuum and how the symmetries are broken. Thus, the answer is in principle yes, in practice no.

The question about the number of parameters is difficult because of the way it looks right now you have to pick the vacuum and the mechanism for breaking various symmetries, each of which introduces parameters or at least other choices for which there are no selection criteria. It is conceivable that these choices can be derived at some point, but at least right now it is clearly not possible, which means that you have a presumably huge number of parameters to fix.